# Karma wait for void containing promise to be done

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

In my component's ngOnInit() I am calling a getAllUsers method which makes an UserService promise call. I want to simply make this test :

```
it('should get initialized', async(inject([MockBackend], (backend: MockBackend) => {
    spyOn(component, "getAllUsers")

    component.ngOnInit()

    expect(component.getAllUsers).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(component.users).not.toBeNull()
    expect(component.users.length).toBe(2)
  })))
```

So in my code I have this :

```
ngOnInit() {
      this.getAllUsers()
}
```

with getAllUsers like this :

```
getAllUsers() {
    this._userService.getAllUsers().toPromise().then(
        data => {
            this.users = data["users"]
        }, error => {}
    )
}
```

and in my MockUserService I have getAllUsers() like that :

```
getAllUsers(): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of({
        "success": true,
        "users": [ User.testUser(), User.testUser() ]
    })
}
```

The thing is I put some console.info at some points in my code and I can see that the expect lines are called even before entering inside component.getAllUsers.

How can I wait for ngOnInit() to be finished? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait before `ngOnInit` finishes running. Make use of `fixture.whenStable()`.Once your asynchronous calls are completed, code within that block will be executed.

```
 it('should get initialized', async(inject([MockBackend], (backend: MockBackend) => {

 fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ComponentName); // replace with the name of your component
    spyOn(component, "getAllUsers")

     component.ngOnInit();
     fixture.detectChanges();
     fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
            expect(component.getAllUsers).toHaveBeenCalled()
            expect(component.users).not.toBeNull()
            expect(component.users.length).toBe(2)
     });
  })))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Now strangely it doesn't even seem to go inside getAllUsers, I did put a logger just before `this.getAllUsers()` and one at the first line of getAllUsers() and this one isn't even printed

Comment: Your `'getAllUsers()'` in component is expecting two parameters, but you are not sending any `params` there. That should be throwing you an error.

Comment: Sorry that's a mistake on my side putting stuff on stackoverflow as I try to simplify what I have to remove what can't be wrong.

Comment: So I managed to make it work with your solution Amit, but I actually had to remove the spyOn line and the expect toHaveBeenCalled, without it it works, with it it doesn't go in the method. Has anyone an idea why?

Comment: Can you try this `spyOn(component, "getAllUsers").and.callThrough();`. Ref : https://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html

Comment: Oh you're right! It works! So just a spyOn without a .and.something() will block to go inside. Thank you very much!